# How to set a custom style on a switch

Tags: android, android-styles

I have been trying to set a custom style for the past 3 hours, and it's been very frustrating.  I use http://android-holo-colors.com/ for all my styles and it suggests I use switch-backport.  I have tried this but can not figure out a way to customize the switch to match my applications colors.

How does one set the colors of the Switch, with or without an extra library?

Note: The switch I am trying to customize is on a Preference Screen.

Comment: also please edit your question since you are talking about a switch and the question reads about a spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use switch-backport and in order to match the colors according to your application, you will have to create your own drawables with the colors. since the switch-backport uses nine-patch images, you could either create your own nine-patch images, or else create drawables using shape.

Hope that helps.!

You could pull the project from [here](https://github.com/hearbeathorror/Switch-Compat-Changing-Colors) for a better understanding.

Comment: Did what you did with the style, only I used [android-switch-backport](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) since I can add it with gradle.  Works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `android:thumb` and `android:track` to your own drawable in order to customize a switch.

I did this in my preferences screen by creating a custom view that extended from `SwitchPreference`, and setting the thumb, track, and background of this custom view.

Then in my `preferences.xml`, instead of putting `SwitchPreference` I put this:

```
<com.path.tofile.CustomSwitchPreference
    android:key="key"
    android:title="title" />
```

Comment: That being said, this only works on most devices. I've seen some Samsung devices override my switch and use the custom Samsung one

Comment: Also when you say you are setting them are you doing this in the custom SwitchPreference Java file?

Comment: I've tested it on api level 14 and above.
That is correct, I am setting them in the custom file